# Django formset custom render error: ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple formset:

```
TextAdFormset = formset_factory(TextAdForm, formset=BaseFormSet, max_num=3)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = CampaignForm(request.POST)
    text_ad_formset = TextAdFormset(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() and text_ad_formset.is_valid():
        ....
else:
    form = CampaignForm()
    text_ad_formset = TextAdFormset()
```

which is being rendered customly in the template:

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ text_ad_formset.management_form }}

    {% for text_ad_form in text_ad_formset.forms %}
        {{ text_ad_form.headline1 }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Error I get:

```
ValidationError at /
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

Debugging:

- My code **WORKS PERFECTLY** with one form. It doesn't work with 2/3 forms in the formset
- I inspected html and TOTAL FORMS are being correctly updated by {{ management_form}}

Django version 1.11

Any ideas how I could debug this problem ?

**UPDATE:**

I've checked POST data which is being submitted in formset. When only one form is being submitted it works correctly:

```
u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'1']
```

However when I submit formset with two forms it comes up with a list:

```
u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2', u'']
```

And in debug screen in browser in POST data it is being shown as:

```
form-TOTAL_FORMS    u''
```

Could this be a possibly related to error ?